# Uncaught ReferenceError: myMethod is not defined

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

my.phtml

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    ".product-item-row": {
        "voide_Module/js/my-js": {}
    }
}
</script>
<div class="product-item-row">
   <div data-bind="click: function(){myMethod()}">
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that `myMethod` does not exist within the scope of the current executing context.  you can use the Inspect Element of your browser, then go to the debug console and enter `ko.dataFor($0)` it should return the object that is currently bound to selected element.  hopefully that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)
But i dont want to use scope. I am using ``".product-item-row"`` (class selector).
If i use scope then it affect on another js.